# telecomManager.acceptRingingCall() is not working in android O

Tags: android

In the new release(Android O) they said that TelecomManager class will have acceptRingingCall() method, by the help of which an incoming call can be received automatically. I tried but it's not accepting the call automatically. I want this feature in my app. I tried in nougat and marshmallow in different ways but it's not working. Here is the code that i tried in Android O:

```
public void autoanswer() {
    TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
   telecomManager.acceptRingingCall();
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
```

Here is Runtime Dependeny:

```
private void RequestMultiplePermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean AnswerPermission = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (AnswerPermission) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public boolean CheckingPermissionIsEnabledOrNot() {
    int AnswerPhoneResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS);
    return (AnswerPhoneResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: worked for me on emulator, still need to check in real device

Answer (score 0):

Do you receive a SecurityException?  A SecurityException is thrown if you do not have the permission, or if the user has not yet granted the runtime permission.

Comment: no, i am getting any error. I already have added runtime permission.

Comment: Without seeing logs its tough to say.  If you can post a bug report or log messages from when the method is called it would help.